# IAM - How to restrict access on queue creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Below is the rule:

```
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - "sqs:CreateQueue"
          - "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
          - "sqs:DeleteQueue"
        Resource: "*"
        Condition:
          ForAllValues:StringEquals:
            cloudformation:TemplateUrl: !Sub "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${AWS::AccountId}/some_queue*”
```

---

that we use to allow any `Principal` to create queues with name starting with `some_queue*`.

but am not sure, if I need to use `Resource: "*"` with `Condition` that restricts access to only create `some_queue*`

---

Can we rewrite this in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the better version of the required policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:CreateQueue",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789:some_queue*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can limit the CreateQueue operation on a resource using wild cards.

For more details, check out the links below:

[Amazon SQS API Permissions: Actions and Resource Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-permissions-reference.html)

[Basic Examples of IAM Policies for Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-iam-policies.html)